# Bootstrap won't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Yes I'm new and yes this is probably not even a real problem, but it still bugs me...

This is what i got...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Emmet & Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="dist/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: File structure]

And this is what i get...

[image: Result]

What have i missed? (I'm running this in Chrome using the Brackets (node.js based) live preview)

**EDIT1:**
`@Nhan` I want the smallest possible bit of html that's still valid in the scenes of bootstrap. I.e. The least amount of rows that still change appearance if i exclude the bootstrap.css. I'm not looking for a specific "look" i just want to learn the fundamentals of bootstrap, from the ground up (I.e. i have no interest in a flying start / ctrl+c, ctrl+v).

Comment: How do you want it to be? Please post an example screenshot.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: @Nhan i want the smallest possible bit of html that's still valid in the scenes of bootstrap. I.e. The least amount of rows that still change appearance if i exclude the bootstrap.css. I'm not looking for a specific "look" i just want to learn the fundamentals of bootstrap, from the ground up (I.e. i have no interest in a flying start / ctrl+c, ctrl+v)

Comment: @Olian04 what do you mean by 'The least amount of rows that still change appearance if i exclude the bootstrap css'? The behavior you showed in the screenshot is what lists do when not modified by CSS.

Comment: @Olian04 Also, if you really want to learn how bootstrap works the best place for you to look is the page I linked in my answer. Don't want to copy and paste? That's fine. Write things in manually tag by tag and watch how they change the output. There's really not a whole lot of reducing to be done as most of the styling is achieved using multi-tiered class specifications and the like.

Comment: @JBartus I know that the result I'm getting is because the list isn't being affected by any css. But what I'm looking for is the least amount of tags necessary in order for the list TO be affected by the bootstrap css. I doubt that I would have to add 50+ rows (your example) in order to see any difference.

Comment: @JBartus I'm sorry that you are unable to understand me. Though it seems like Nhan understood me just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean. Below is the minimal markup required to implement a Bootstrap navbar:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- navbar-default: default colour scheme -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

  <!-- Bootstrap container -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Toggle menu on smaller screen sizes (mobile) -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> + </button>

    <!-- Bootstrap collapse, work with the button above -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

      <!-- Link list -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Negative. Navbar header is optional for one, as are the collapse bits though I'd generally advise against removing those as the ability for it to collapse is part and parcel of its responsive behavior. This is why I have advised him to start from the end (the <li> tags) and work back til he gets his desired result because there's much that goes into it. Sniffing around the components page with the developer tools to see how things interact and trial and error will eventually get whatever it is he's hoping to achieve

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the entirety of the header is optional.

Comment: Gonna clarify further for a second. In the header the logo is entirely optional and if one opts to get rid of the collapsing functionality the button is too.

Comment: Yeah so I moved the button outside, the collapsing is needed for mobile devices.

Comment: Yes and no, you can opt not to have collapsing if your menu is small enough, but you're generally correct, you wouldn't want to, which is what I said in my first comment. :P

Answer (score 2):

You're missing about 90% of the navbar related structure. From: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Bootstrap is almost certainly fine, you just need to provide it with the correct working materials to style. I put your navbar code into a bootstrap page I know works and got the exact same output you're seeing due to the lack of appropriate styles and structure.